# How to repeat json code in AWS States Language (ASL)

Tags: json, amazon-web-services

I have a step function that has 14 states. Each state is exactly the same, except for the command. Is there a way to repeat the same state only changing the name in ASL rather than have a huge json file with the same entries over and over?

```
{
  "Comment": "ECS RunTask Jobs",
  "StartAt": "ECS RunTask 01",
  "States": {
    "ECS RunTask 01": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "{some resource}",
      "Parameters": "{"LaunchType":"FARGATE" and some parameters}",
      "Next": "ECS RunTask 02",
      "ResultSelector": { "commands": ["command1"] },
      "Catch": "Send Email Error"

    "ECS RunTask 02": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "{resources have the same values as ECS RunTask 01}",
      "Parameters": "{parameters have the same values as ECS RunTask 01}",
      "Next": "ECS RunTask 03",
      "ResultSelector": { "commands": ["command2"] },
      "Catch": "Send Email Error"

    "ECS RunTask 03": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": {"resources have the same values as ECS Run Task01"},
      "Parameters": {"parameters have the same values as ECS RunTask 01}"
      "Next": "ECS RunTask 04",
      "ResultSelector": { "commands": ["command3"] },
      "Catch": "Send Email Error"

    "ECS Run Task04": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": {"resources have the same values as ECS RunTask 01"},
      "Parameters": {"parameters have the same values as ECS RunTask 01"},
      "Next": "ECS RunTask 05",
      "ResultSelector": { "commands": ["command4"] },
      "Catch": "Send Email Error"
    
...   after all RunTask completed, "Send Email Complete"
}
```

Comment: Do you use any IaC? Terraform, CDK, CFN etc.?

Comment: I am using Terraform.

Comment: Why are all the tasks the same?

Comment: I am using ECS. Each task is a container running a script that does some data processing (I don't use Lambda for this because it times out from the data fetching). All the resources are parameters that are used to set the environment for the container, but they all use pretty much the same container conditions.

Comment: After looking at the questions you asked, I realized my question needed a bit more detail, so I updated it